# terraform create AKS use existing application gateway seem to be broken

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm pretty sure there's a recent change? seems I can't use existing app gateway as AGIC for aks anymore in terraform

```
ingress_application_gateway {

      subnet_id    = var.ingress_agic_subnet == null ? null : data.azurerm_subnet.ingress_agic_subnet[0].id # existing subnet where I created App gateway
      gateway_id   = var.ingress_application_gateway_id #existing  app gateway ID
    

    }
```

the error message keeps saying

```
│ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│
│   with module.aks.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.this,
│   on terraform-azurerm-lab3-aks\main.tf line 70, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "this":
│   70:       subnet_id    = var.ingress_agic_subnet == null ? null : data.azurerm_subnet.ingress_agic_subnet[0].id
│
│ "ingress_application_gateway.0.subnet_id": conflicts with ingress_application_gateway.0.gateway_id
╵
╷
│ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│
│   with module.aks.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.this,
│   on terraform-azurerm-lab3-aks\main.tf line 73, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "this":
│   73:       gateway_id   = var.ingress_application_gateway_id
│
│ "ingress_application_gateway.0.gateway_id": conflicts with ingress_application_gateway.0.subnet_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [***stephybun***](https://github.com/stephybun) for your suggestion over the GitHub Disccusion related to same issue. Posting this as an asnwer to help other community member as well.

> The AKS API will create an Application Gateway for you based on the
> subnet_id or subnet_cidr provided, or you can BYO Application Gateway.
> As a result it isn't possible to specify both subnet_id and gateway_id
> since that would trigger conflicting behaviours in the API. Since you
> already have an existing Application Gateway the only property you
> need to set is the gateway_id.

***Reference : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15693***

Even you can follow this [***Microsoft Documennt***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing#enable-the-agic-add-on-in-existing-aks-cluster-through-portal) which mention the same ***Enable the AGIC add-on in existing AKS cluster*** you only require **`gateway_id`**